# Difficulty deploying to Galaxy Watch from Xamarin (and Tizen Studio)

Tags: c#, xamarin, deployment, watch, tizen

Check certificate error [-12] failed
I'm having extraordinary difficulty deploying to the Galaxy watch (Latest 4.0.0 os)
Deploys fine to simulator

To date. Generated a new certificate as the one for 2018 had expired - some point here - 
1. Went to Tizen Package Manager and downloaded everything in the Extension  SDK anything remotely watch related.
2. Found that the watch connection nearly always needs ping NN.NN.NN.NN -t to ensure a the connection manager finds it (although seems the Xamarin Tized - found in the VS Menu - right click on menu, select Tizen seemed to be more consistent than Tizen's Device Manager (PS. I also forced the DNS in my router to give IP Address to the Watches Mac)
3. I've had to struggle at every stage to get the watch connected -

Got an example off Git hub (HeartRateMonitor)

The app compiles fine (and deploys fine to sim) but fails deploy to watch with Check certificate error [-12] failed - in debug / deploy log and 'Current certificate is invalid for selected device' in MS VS Popup after deploy complete. After using Xamarin for several apps / Andriod / Ios / Apple Watch / Windows this is the first real problem (Was amazed how easy it was to do IOS after I p..d my patch with a Mac.
Several hours on the Samsung site reveals little.

Answer (score 2):

I found the [Certificate Manager page](https://developer.tizen.org/development/visual-studio-tools-tizen/tools/certificate-manager) on the Visual Studio Tools for Tizen page helpful to resolve the issue.

Essentially:

1. In Visual Studio, go to Tools -> Options -> Tizen -> Certification.
2. Check the option for **Sign the .TPK file using the following option.**
3. Use the **Use profile of Tizen Certificate Manager** to manage certificates through the Certificate Manager.
4. Close options, clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Where are these options in the Mac version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Answered my own question. On Mac it's in Project -> Solution Options -> Tizen -> Certification.